# What is this typography in this variable?

Tags: math-mode, typography, algorithms

I am wondering how to get "gamma2" to have the same font as in

[image]

Doing

```
gamma2 = \Gamma (\alpha + 2)
```

gives the wanted equation, but "gamma2" does not have the font of the example.

How can I get the typography shown above for "gamma2" ?

Comment: Since you text is in math mode, use `\mathtt{}`. For texts, use `\texttt{}`.

Comment: This needs copyediting: As it is it's hard to understand the question.

Comment: @MartinSchröder, I didn't understand your comment. Don't you agree that the OP wants to use `mathtt`?

Comment: Since it looks like a mix of math and some source code listings and its `\lstinline{...}` might be useful (especially if one ends up with function names like `some_function=...`

Comment: @Sigur: Maybe. But "I think what is this " is not correct english.

Comment: @MartinSchröder, oh, I see.

Comment: @daleif Can you give one example about **lstinline**? Is it suitable for multiline code block and pseudocode. I have now this http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/210441/13173

Comment: See the listings manual, just search for lstinline. Listings can be used for showing of code, for pseudo code I prefer a more formalized approach, e.g. using algorithmic (I think it is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does a combination of a math environment and `\mathtt` (as suggested by @Sigur ) provide the desired result?

E.g.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$\mathtt{gamma2} = \Gamma (\alpha + 2)$
\end{document}
```